# Android emulator cannot connect to IIS deployed site

Tags: android, iis-7, android-emulator, connection

I have deployed my site on IIS 7. I want to consume some services written in that site by Android emulator. If I run that website locally (using Visual Studio), I can connect to site through Android emulator. But I specify address for IIS deployed site, it cannot connect thus throws an exception. Any ideas how to get rid of this problem? Do I have to make any settings in IIS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add the IP address of your system within the IIS Express applicationhost.config file bindings sections.

```
<bindings>
<binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:40000:localhost" />
<binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:40000:192.168.5.118" />
</bindings>
```

Replace with your own address and port.